# How to redirect user to an error page when 404 error occurred

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I am trying to redirect the user to a page when 404 error occurred, so I am writing

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error.html
```

In `.htaccess` file and having an `error.html` file in my root directory but it's giving me

> The requested URL was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: You may be need to put an absolute path for error.html like `/home/web/error.html`.

Comment: Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file? If so, please add the complete file to your question - you may have a conflict. (You should not use an absolute filesystem path as mentioned by @Jon. The path is a root-relative URL-path, as you appear to be using.)

Comment: @MrWhite NO i just have this in my .htaccess file

Comment: Do you have access to the server config?

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting the error document to the system default prior to setting your custom document. For example:

```
ErrorDocument 404 default
ErrorDocument 404 /error.html
```

On some shared servers, the error document is (incorrectly) preconfigured in the main server config.

Comment: Do you have other directives in your `.htaccess` file? Do you have any other `.htaccess` files along the file system path?

Comment: Are `.htaccess` overrides enabled (ie. the appropriate `AllowOverride` directive in the server config)? If you request the error document directly does it work? eg. `example.com/error.html`